# can i view the DOM as a tree graph?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, tree, firebug

I would like to see the dom of my xhtml page in the form a tree/ graph - in the form of an inverted tree or even otherwise. I tried firebug, DOM Inspector, which displays the dom structure well, but it is in the form of collapsible tree (like you click on + and it displays the branches, and again click + to get the subbranches etc..). While this is fine, I am looking to see if the same can be displayed, sort of, in the form an image, so that visualisation is better.

Any tools that do this?

Thanks!

Comment: you do realise how huge this tree gets, right? For most websites with any kind of complexity, it'll be unmanageably big if you just have the whole thing expanded all the way with no way to collapse bits of it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://www.burlaca.com/2009/02/html2gdl-graphviz/

It's a -

> script that creates the graph of a html file/url for aiSee graph
>   layout software [*or GraphViz*]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the application, you could try [HTML tree generator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-tree-generator/dlbbmhhaadfnbbdnjalilhdakfmiffeg), a plugin for Google Chrome